# How NOT to reduce fractions

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

### Reducing fractions *the wrong way*

In this code-golf challenge you have to find fractions that can be reduced the wrong way but still end up in the same number.

**Note:** reducing fractions *the wrong way* does here have an exact definition, see details.

Example:

64/16 = <strike>6</strike>4/1<strike>6</strike>=4/1 = 4

Of course you cannot just strike both 6es but here you still end up with the correct value. In this challenge you have to find examples like this.

#### Details

You have to write a function/program that accepts one positive integer `n` as input and outputs/returns a list/array of the fractions in format
`numerator1,denominator1,numerator2,denominator2,...`

The program has to find out for each fraction `a/b` with `a+b=n` and `a,b>0` whether it can be reduced *the wrong way*. (It does not matter whether if it can be reduced in the conventional way or whether there are many possibilities of reductions, it just has to be possible to reduce it *the wrong way* in at least one way.)

**Definition of** ***the wrong way:*** A fraction can be reduced *the wrong way* if and only if the same sequence of successive digits appears in a and b *and* if the value of the fraction stays the same if you remove the substring.

Example: 1536/353 can be 'reduced' to 16/3 but those two values are not equal so you cannot reduce this fraction *the wrong way*.

Note that this definition of reducing *the wrong way* can also include fractions that are reduced the right way: `110/10 = 11/1` is within the definition of reducing *the wrong way* even though it is a valid step.

#### Scoring

The least number of bytes wins. You can write a function or program that accepts an integer and returns an array or a program that uses stdin/stdout or you can consider n saved in a variable and in the end of the program the list must be saved in an other variable.

#### Test cases

Please include following testcases (Tell me which ones I should add, I have no idea how many of those fractions there are / how many examples to expect)

```
n=80 (64/16 should be in this list)
n=147 (98/49 should be in this list)
n=500 (294/196 should be in this list) WRONG since 294+196 != 500 Thanks Falko
```

Comment: I'm guessing `a` and `b` are constrained to positive integers?

Comment: Or if we had two negative numbers, crossing out the '-' would be another great way to reduce the right and wrong way.

Comment: Consider defining a term for "the wrong way", such as "goofy" or "freaky". I think the post would be easier to understand, because readers immediately grok that there must be a definition for the term.

Comment: What if there are multiple ways to reduce a fraction and only some of them are wrong? `1010/10 = 101/1 && 1010/10 /= 110/1`

Comment: Variant of https://projecteuler.net/problem=33 ?

Comment: @ JanDvorak you just have to determine whether a fraction **can** be reduced *the wrong way*. @ MichaelEaster: Ok I will think abou this. (Thats why I wrote it in italic but perhaps that is not enough.) @ user80551: I did not remember this problem, I just got this example from my algebra teacher=)

Comment: Your second test case (`n=147`) is incorrect: `49/89 != 4/8`.

Comment: If there's more than one way to reduce a fraction, may we include it multiple times in the result set?

Comment: does it matter if the digits are not in the same order in the numerator and denominator, or if the digits aren't close together? you used the word 'sequence' when defining "reducing the wrong way" which implies that it does matter, but to me it doesn;t seem to be less "reducing the wrong way".

Comment: @proudhaskeller If in doubt, follow the definition rather than intuition. That's what definitions are for. I have followed the definition in my answer.

Comment: @proudhaskeller You could of cours make different definitions but you guessed correctly: according to mine the order matters!

Comment: Am I wrong or is your third test case invalid, since 500!=294+196?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes. @ Falko: you aren't wrowng, this is a mistake. (I think Beta Decay added this one).

Comment: @flawr: You seem to have missed [Jan Dvorak’s question regarding your challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37794/how-not-to-reduce-fractions?noredirect=1#comment86503_37794).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Python 2 – <s>183</s> 180

```python
r=range
s=lambda a:[(a[i:j],int(a[:i]+a[j:]))for i in r(len(a))for j in r(i+1,len(a)+(i>0))]
l=sum([[a,n-a]for a in r(n)for p,x in s(`a`)for q,y in s(`n-a`)if(n-a)*x==a*y<p==q],[])
```

the input must be stored in `n`, the output will be stored in `l`.

#### Test cases:

n = 80:

```
[10, 70, 16, 64, 20, 60, 30, 50, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 30, 60, 20, 64, 16, 70, 10]
```

n = 147:

```
[49, 98, 98, 49]
```

n =490:

```
[10, 480, 20, 470, 30, 460, 40, 450, 50, 440, 60, 430, 70, 420, 80, 410, 90, 400, 90, 400, 98, 392, 100, 390, 100, 390, 110, 380, 120, 370, 130, 360, 140, 350, 150, 340, 160, 330, 170, 320, 180, 310, 190, 300, 190, 300, 196, 294, 200, 290, 200, 290, 210, 280, 220, 270, 230, 260, 240, 250, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 250, 240, 260, 230, 270, 220, 280, 210, 290, 200, 290, 200, 294, 196, 300, 190, 300, 190, 310, 180, 320, 170, 330, 160, 340, 150, 350, 140, 360, 130, 370, 120, 380, 110, 390, 100, 390, 100, 392, 98, 400, 90, 400, 90, 410, 80, 420, 70, 430, 60, 440, 50, 450, 40, 460, 30, 470, 20, 480, 10]
```

---

Should duplicates in the output be forbidden, it gets 10 characters longer:

```python
r=range
s=lambda a:[(a[i:j],int(a[:i]+a[j:]))for i in r(len(a))for j in r(i+1,len(a)+(i>0))]
l=sum(map(list,{(a,n-a)for a in r(n)for p,x in s(`a`)for q,y in s(`n-a`)if(n-a)*x==a*y<p==q}),[])
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Haskell, <del>207</del> 206 (209?) characters

```hs
import Data.List
x![]=[x];(w:x)!(y:z)|w==y=x!z;_!_=[]
a@(w:x)%b=a!b++[w:e|e<-x%b];a%b=a!b
h=show
f n=[(c,n-c)|c<-[1..n-1],i<-inits$h c,s<-init$tails i,s/=h c,a<-h c%s,b<-h(n-c)%s,read a*(n-c)==read('0':b)*c]
```

If it's not allowable to return the same ratio more than once (400/400 = 40/40 = 4/4), use `f n=nub[...` to filter them out.

Returns a list of pairs. A list of two-element pairs costs the same. A list of actual fractions would require importing `Data.Ratio` or fully qualifying `Data.Ratio.%` (which also collides with the `%` function defined here)

**test cases** (with `nub`):

```hs
Prelude Data.List> f 80
[(10,70),(16,64),(20,60),(30,50),(40,40),(50,30),(60,20),(64,16),(70,10)]
Prelude Data.List> f 147
[(49,98),(98,49)]
Prelude Data.List> f 500
[(10,490),(20,480),(30,470),(40,460),(50,450),(60,440),(70,430),(80,420),(90,410
),(100,400),(110,390),(120,380),(130,370),(140,360),(150,350),(160,340),(170,330
),(180,320),(190,310),(200,300),(210,290),(220,280),(230,270),(240,260),(250,250
),(260,240),(270,230),(280,220),(290,210),(300,200),(310,190),(320,180),(330,170
),(340,160),(350,150),(360,140),(370,130),(380,120),(390,110),(400,100),(410,90)
,(420,80),(430,70),(440,60),(450,50),(460,40),(470,30),(480,20),(490,10)]
```

**ungolfed and commented**:

```hs
import Data.List

-- haystack ! needle - the haystack with the needle removed, wrapped in a single-element list
--                       or an empty array if the haystack does not start with the needle

x ! [] = [x]                        -- case: empty needle = match with the full haystack left
(h:hs) ! (n:ns) | h == n = hs ! ns  -- case: needle and haystack match
_ ! _ = []                          -- case: no match

-- haystack % needle - the haystack with the needle removed 
--                       for all positions of the needle in the haystack

a@(h:hs) % b = a ! b ++ map (h:) (hs%b) -- either remove the needle here, or elsewhere
a % b = a                               -- empty haystack cannot be popped

-- f - the function we are interested in

f total = [ (num, total - num) 
          | num   <- [1 .. total-1],            -- for each numerator in range
            i     <- inits $ show num,          -- for each postfix of the numerator
            sub   <- init $ tails i,            -- for each prefix of the postfix except the last (empty) one
            sub /= show num,                    -- that isn't equal to the numerator
            reNum <- show num % sub,            -- remove the substring from the numerator
            reDiv <- show (total - num) % sub,  -- as well as from the denominator.

                                                -- the resulting ratios must be equal by value:
            (read reNum) ^ (total - num) == (read '0':reDiv) * num]
```

Comment: can you change ';' to newlines (in the golfed code)? it doesn't change the byte count and it makes the code much more readable

Comment: @proudhaskeller That's deliberate; I like having fewer lines in the golfed code. Also, the line lengths are more balanced this way. Do you think I should change?

Comment: do whatever you want, but i would like the lines to be spread out so i would be able to read the code better (rather then resorting to the ungolfed code)

Comment: Are you fine with the current version? I can't split the last line, unfortunately (except at spaces, which would kill readability)

Comment: as I said, do whatever you feel like

Comment: won't this not allow reducing digits which aren't the same order in the numerator and the denominator, or which aren't close together?

Comment: That's the desired behavior; "iff the same sequence of digits appears in a and b and ..."

Comment: I don't see what makes these less of reducing fractions the wrong way. i'll ask the person who wrote the question.

Comment: @proudhaskeller removing more than one subsequence at the same time results in a reduction that doesn't follow the definition in the question.

Comment: by the way, you could golf it by removing the requirement `sub/=[]` and instead adding replacing `tails i` with `tail$tails i`

Comment: @proudhaskeller thanks, implemented (except the empty one is the last one, not the first one)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - 302

***Note:*** Due to parsing difficulties, there are no fractions with the number 0 in (so no fractions are calculated using the correct method).

```
n=int(input());s=str;r=range
print([[a,b]for a in r(1,n)for b in r(1,a)for i in r(1,n)if i!=a and i!=b and s(i)in s(a)and s(i)in s(b)and s(a).count(s(i))<len(s(a))and s(b).count(s(i))<len(s(b))and not'0'in s(a)and not'0'in s(b)and eval(s(a).replace(s(i),'')+'/'+s(b).replace(s(i),''))==a/b and a+b<=n])
```

#### With n=80:

```
[[64, 16]]
```

#### With n=147

```
[[64, 16], [65, 26], [95, 19], [98, 49]]
```

#### With n=500

```
[[64, 16], [65, 26], [95, 19], [98, 49], [136, 34], [192, 96], [194, 97], [195, 39], [196, 49], [196, 98], [231, 132], [238, 34], [238, 136], [242, 143], [253, 154], [264, 165], [268, 67], [275, 176], [286, 187], [291, 97], [291, 194], [294, 49], [294, 98], [294, 196], [295, 59], [297, 198], [298, 149], [325, 13], [341, 143], [345, 138], [392, 49], [392, 98], [395, 79]]
```

Comment: For `n=80` this prints `[[64, 16], [65, 26]]`, but obviously `65 + 26 = 91 > 80`.

Comment: Turn all the `if`s into a single big `if` with `and`s connecting all the conditions? Saves quite a few chars, I think.

Comment: @Soham Yes, it does, thanks!

Comment: Could you also include the testcases I've added? (And could you perhaps see if you find some interesting test cases I should add too?)

Comment: @flawr Your requested test cases added

Comment: This is missing the reciprocals.

Comment: Where are `10/70`, `20/60` and `30/50`?

Comment: @Comintern are they supposed to be there?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'd assume so, the spec of `a/b` with `a+b=n` and `a,b>0` wouldn't exclude them.

Comment: @Comintern true; good catch

Comment: you also assume `a + b <= n` whereas the question is `a + b == n`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 - 236

```
n=input()
r=range
f=float
l=len
for a in r(n):
 A=`a`;B=`n-a`
 for i in r(l(A)):
  for j in r(i+1,l(A)+1):
   for u in r(l(B)):
    C=A[:i]+A[j:];D=B[:u]+B[u+j-i:]
    if A[i:j]==B[u:u+j-i]and l(C)*l(D)and f(C)==f(A)/f(B)*f(D):print A,B
```