# Complementary colors

Tags: code-golf

Given an input of a color in `#rrggbb` hex format, output its RGB complement in
the same format.

The RGB complement R<sub>2</sub>G<sub>2</sub>B<sub>2</sub> of any color
R<sub>1</sub>G<sub>1</sub>B<sub>1</sub> is defined as the color with
R<sub>2</sub> value *255 - R<sub>1</sub>*, B<sub>2</sub> value *255 -
B<sub>1</sub>*, and G<sub>2</sub> value *255 - G<sub>1</sub>*.

Hex digits may be either in uppercase (#FFAA20) or lowercase (#ffaa20). The
case of the input and output need not be consistent (so you may take input in
lowercase but output in uppercase, and vice versa).

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins.

Test cases (note that since giving your program/function its own output should
result in the original input (it is
[involutory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))), the test
cases should work in both directions):

```
In/Out   Out/In
----------------
#ffffff  #000000
#abcdef  #543210
#badcab  #452354
#133742  #ecc8bd
#a1b2c3  #5e4d3c
#7f7f80  #80807f
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but sRGB doesn't work that way. You should convert to linear space first, which hex-codes aren't in.

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh well. The state of the challenge will reflect my ignorance, then, since I can't really change it now. :P

Comment: Averaging two values in sRGB could be a decent separate challenge, though. sRGB = RGB^0.45 over most of the range, but linear near the bottom of the range.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Pyth, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Thanks to @isaacg for -1 byte!*

```
sXz.HM16
```

Subtracting a certain color's value from 255 is equivalent to subtracting each of its hexadecimal digits from 15. Say a number is ***16a+b***. Then the value of the number created by subtracting its digits from 15 is ***16(15-a) + (15-b) = 255 - (16a+b)***.

```
sXz.HM16     implicit: z=input()
      16      
   .HM        map hex representation over range
   .HM16     '0123456789abcdef'
  z           the input string
 X            Translate characters in x1 present in x2 to reversed x2
              that is, '0' becomes f, '1' becomes 'e', and so on.
              The initial '#' is unchanged.
s             That produced a list, so join into a string by reducing +
```

Try it [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sXz.HM16&input=%23a1b2c3&debug=1). [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sXz.HM16&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%23ffffff%0A%23000000%0A%0A%23abcdef%0A%23543210%0A%0A%23badcab%0A%23452354%0A%0A%23133742%0A%23ecc8bd%0A%0A%23a1b2c3%0A%235e4d3c%0A%0A%237f7f80%0A%2380807f&debug=1)

Comment: Nice answer! I borrowed your idea of using `'0123456789abcdef'` to convert to hex (instead of `dec2hex` function)

Comment: I think your link is incorrect. ([Copy-paste FTW.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68304/30164))

Comment: @Pietu1998 Whoops; I'll fix it.

Comment: The `U` is unnecessary - it's implicitly filled in by `M`.

Answer (score 7):

## Retina, <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
T`w`G-A9-0
```

There are three parts to the code, separated by backticks (`` ` ``): `T` specifies transliterate mode, which replaces each character in the second part with its corresponding character in the third part.

`w` is the same as traditional regex's `\w`, or `_0-9A-Za-z`, which is expanded to `_0123456789ABCDEFGH...`.

The second part is expanded to `GFEDCBA9876543210`, thanks to Retina's nifty ability to expand in reverse order. Put these on top of each other, and we get:

```
_0123456789ABCDEFGH...
GFEDCBA987654321000...
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that the last character, `0`, is repeated to fit the length of the longer string, but we only care about the hexadecimal characters, shown by carets.

Thanks to Martin Büttner for suggesting this approach.

[Try the test suite online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGB3YEctQTktMA&input=I0ZGRkZGRiAgIzAwMDAwMAojQUJDREVGICAjNTQzMjEwCiNCQURDQUIgICM0NTIzNTQKIzEzMzc0MiAgI0VDQzhCRAojQTFCMkMzICAjNUU0RDNDCiM3RjdGODAgICM4MDgwN0Y)

Comment: Did `R` not exist at the time? In 0.8.2 you can use `Rd` instead of `9-0`, saving a byte. You can also write ``T`dA-F`Ro`` for the same 9 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>74</s> 49 bytes

```julia
h->"#"join([hex(15-parse(Int,i,16))for i=h[2:7]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcvNisMgGIXhvVchdaOQDlGTGgYyzKow11C68Jd8EmxQC3P3GZPlvLvzwInvFfRtv8/7cv26kEt8QaKPxf9SPl43nYunP6l20PEbY@GVMczLQ3yq55Ptx6TQ4cgwJFy2FeoHzV67FZIvlDGEW9@6FJ8rvlNgeJ5x/KfxVEA@ObRlSHVNtOa3ZzsJZxiT/gwRbazzB4yDFLyB0c5q02AYhRwHRLiUahANvLWTce3CjbDyuPjBSYuICipMfYOpn3oV/gA)

Pretty long at the moment but it's a start. This is a lambda function that accepts a string and returns a string. The output will be in lowercase but the input can be in either.

As [Thomas noted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68309/20469), subtracting each 2-digit color component from 255 is equivalent to subtracting each individual digit in the hexadecimal input from 15. Looping over the input string, excluding the leading `#`, we convert 15 - the parsed digit to hexadecimal. We join all of these then tack on a `#` and call it good.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, 61 bytes <s>66 68 48 53 64</s>

*Saves quite a few bytes thanks to @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ, @NinjaBearMonkey, and @nderscore*

```
s=>"#"+(1e5+(8**8+~('0x'+s.slice(1))).toString(16)).slice(-6)
```

Takes advantage of auto-type-casting. Fixing the zeros killed the byte count

Comment: Use ``eval(`0x${s.slice(1)}`)`` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ That's the same length?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ thanks, I  used `-`  instead of eval which saved even more bytes

Comment: Oh, forgot about auto type casting :D

Comment: Try it with the input `#FFFFFF`. Returns `#0`.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ thanks, didn't see that but it's fix killed the byte cubit

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ Yeah, sorry. Noticed it when working on a Jolf answer.

Comment: You should be able to use `1e5` instead of the string of zeroes.

Comment: -5 bytes using `1e5` and bitflip `~`: `s=>"#"+(1e5+(8**8+~('0x'+s.slice(1))).toString(16)).slice(-6)`

Comment: Sure, but that's now ES7.

Comment: You don't have to fiddle around with zeros. Simply use `8**9` and you guarantee a leading `8` which you simply `slice` off: `s=>'#'+(8**9+~('0x'+s.slice(1))).toString(16).slice(1)` (54 bytes); ES6 version: `s=>'#'+(~('0x'+s.slice(1))<<4>>>4).toString(16).slice(1)` (56 bytes).

Answer (score 4):

## Marbelous, 41 bytes

```
00@0
\\]]\/
-W/\@0
-W
~~
<A+700
+O//]]
+O
```

[Online Interpreter here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40808) Input should be in uppercase.

#### Explanation

The `00` and `]]` at the bottom will fetch the first character (the `#`) and it will fall to the bottom and be outputted before anything else.

The first 3 lines are a loop to fetch all the remaining characters.

First we need to convert the hex digit characters to 0-15, by doing `x -= 48, x -= x > 9 ? 7 : 0` (since `'A' - '9'` is 8).

To find the complement, we simply need to convert every digit `x` to `15-x`. This is equivalent to (for 8-bit values) `(~x)+16 = ~(x-16)`.

Finally, we have to convert these numbers back into hex digits, by doing `x += x > 9 ? 7 : 0, x += 48`.

So now we have `x -= 48, x -= x > 9 ? 7 : 0, x = ~(x - 16), x += x > 9 ? 7 : 0, x += 48`.

Note that if we remove the expression with the first ternary operator, then input digits `A`-`F` will result in a negative x after negation.

Thus we can change the previous expression to: `x -= 48, x -= 16, x = ~x, x += (x > 9 || x < 0) ? 7 : 0, x += 48`, which is equal to `x -= 64, x = ~x, x += (x > 9 || x < 0) ? 7 : 0, x += 48`.

The above code is just an implementation of the last expression. `-W` is `x -= 32` and `+O` is `x += 24`. Since Marbelous uses unsigned 8-bit arithmetic, the condition `<A` covers both the case of `x > 9` and `x < 0`.

Comment: Did you create Marbelous?

Comment: @RikerW Marbelous was created/fleshed out by several PPCG users including myself: [See here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6949/29611).

Comment: Okay. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>63</s> <s>58</s> <s>52</s> 49 bytes

```
c=>c.replace(/\w/g,x=>(15-`0x${x}`).toString(16))
```

*Thanks to [nderscore](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20160/nderscore) for saving 11 bytes!*

Comment: -5 bytes: `c=>"#"+[...c].map(x=>"fedcba9876543210"[+('0x'+x)]).join\`\``

Comment: @nder exactly, thought about it already :) Thanks. Was going to use it, but with "eval".

Comment: ah, I've got one more -6: `c=>c.replace(/\w/g,x=>"fedcba9876543210"[+('0x'+x)])`

Comment: `c=>c.replace(/\w/g,x=>('0x'+x^15).toString(16))`

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
k6ḂĿ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrNuG4gsS/IiwiIiwiYTFiMmMzIl0=)

```
k6ḂĿ
k6   # Hex chars - "012356789abcdef"
  Ḃ  # Bifurcate - push its reverse without popping
   Ŀ # Transliterate the input from the hex chars to the reverse hex chars
```

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 17 bytes

```
pq#-w^88C Li1~560
pq                pad
         _Li1     the input, w/out the first char
        C    ~5   parsed as a base-16 integer (~5 = 16)
    w^88          8 ^ 8 - 1 (the magic number)
   -              subtract the parsed input from said number
  #               convert result to hexadecimal
               60 pad the result with 6 0's
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=cHEjLXdefjU2QyBMaTF-NTYw), [Test suite](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=cHEjLXdeODhDIExpMX41NjA&input=I2ZmZmZmZgoKI2FiY2RlZgoKI2JhZGNhYgoKIzEzMzc0MgoKI2ExYjJjMwoKIzdmN2Y4MA) (Use full run, which now works.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt), <s>35</s> <s>32</s> <s>22</s> <s>20</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
¡Y?(F-XnG)sG :X
```

Explanation:

```
¡                 //Take input and map (shortcut to "Um@"). Input should in the form of "#123456"
 Y?               //if Y is not 0, then return (F-XnG)sG, otherwise last step...
    F-XnG           //Subtract X, converted from hexadecimal (G is 16) to decimal, from 15
          sG        //convert decimal to hexadecimal
             :X   //...otherwise return X unchanged (happens only with #, the first char)
```

Comment: Nice one! I saw this last night and said to myself, "Tomorrow I'll help to golf it down." But by now you've golfed it further than I thought possible. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/6.0.0), 21 bytes

```
35,5Y216,j6L)!16ZA-)h
```

This uses [release 6.0.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/6.0.0) of the language/compiler, which is earlier than the challenge.

Input digits should be uppercase.

#### Example

This has been executed on Octave:

```
>> matl
 > 35,5Y216,j6L)!16ZA-)h
 >
> #FFAA20
#0055DF
```

#### *Edit (June 12, 2016)*

The code can now be [**tried online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MzUgNVkyMTYgajRMKSExNlpBLSlo&input=I0ZGQUEyMA). Commas need to be replaced by spaces, and `6L` by `4L`, to conform to changes in the language.

#### Explanation

```
35,             % number literal: ASCII code of '#'
5Y2             % '0123456789ABCDEF'
16,             % number literal
j               % input string
6L)             % remove first element
!               % transpose
16ZA            % convert from hex to dec
-               % subtract from 16
)               % index into '0123456789ABCDEF' to convert back to hex
h               % prepend 35, which gets automatically converted into '#'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 30 bytes

*includes +1 for `-p`*

```
s/\w/sprintf"%x",15&~hex$&/eg
```

usage: `echo #000000 | perl -p file.pl`
or `echo #000000 | perl -pe 's/\w/sprintf"%x",15&~hex$&/eg'`.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>60</del> <del>41</del> 32 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: be82 00ac cd29 b106 ac3c 397e 022c 272c  .....)...<9~.,',
00000010: 30f6 d03c f976 0204 2704 40cd 29e2 e9c3  0..<.v..'.@.)...
```

**Unassembled listing:**

```
BE 0082     MOV  SI, 82H            ; command line input set to string 
AC          LODSB                   ; load first '#' char 
CD 29       INT  29H                ; write it to console 
B1 06       MOV  CL, 6              ; loop 6 chars 
        INLOOP: 
AC          LODSB                   ; load next ASCII hex char into AL 
3C 39       CMP  AL, '9'            ; is char an alpha (a-f)? 
7E 02       JLE  NOHEX_IN           ; if not, is numeric 
2C 27       SUB  AL, 'f'-'9'-6      ; otherwise ASCII adjust a-f 
        NOHEX_IN: 
2C 30       SUB  AL, '0'            ; ASCII to decimal convert 
F6 D0       NOT  AL                 ; complement the color (magic happens here) 
3C F9       CMP  AL, 0F9H           ; is char <= 9? 
76 02       JBE  NOHEX_OUT          ; if not, is numeric 
04 27       ADD  AL, 'f'-'9'-6      ; otherwise ASCII adjust a-f 
        NOHEX_OUT: 
04 40       ADD  AL, '0'+10H        ; decimal convert to ASCII 
CD 29       INT  29H                ; write char to console 
E2 E9       LOOP INLOOP             ; keep looping 
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
```

So nearly all of this code is brute-force conversion from an ASCII hex string into a numeric value and then back again.  No CPU instructions on x86-16 to help with that I'm afraid!

**I/O:**

Standalone PC DOS executable.  Input via command line, output to `STDOUT`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r\wÈnG'nF
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=clx3yG5HJ25G&input=IiM3ZjdmODAi)

```
r\wÈnG'nF     :Implicit input of string
r             :Replace
 \w           :  RegEx /[0-9a-z]/gi
   È          :  Pass each match through the following function
    n         :    Toggle base
     G        :      16
      'n      :    Subtracting intermediate result from
        F     :      15
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

*[1 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68305/complementary-colors/68307?noredirect=1#comment165760_68307) thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).*

```
%"#%06x"-t^8 8itz16
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22%23%2506x%22-t%5E8+8itz16&input=%23badcab&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22%23%2506x%22-t%5E8+8itz16&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%23ffffff%0A%23abcdef%0A%23badcab%0A%23133742%0A%23a1b2c3%0A%237f7f80&debug=0)

#### Explanation

- `z` is the input
- `tz` removes the `#`
- `itz16` parses as a hexadecimal number
- `t^8 8` calculates 8<sup>8</sup> - 1
- `-t^8 8itz16` calculates 8<sup>8</sup> - 1 - input
- `%"#%06x"-t^2 24itz16` formats it into a zero-padded 6-character hex string and adds the `#`

Comment: How about 8^8 for 2^24?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>69</s> 60 bytes

```
"#"<>IntegerString[8^8-#~StringDrop~1~FromDigits~16-1,16,6]&
```

Once again, it's the string processing that kills me here.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>95</s> 90 bytes

```
String f(String v){return v.format("#%06x",0xFFFFFF^Integer.parseInt(v.substring(1),16));}
```

Bitwise XOR.

Answer (score 1):

### sed, 48 bytes

```
y/0123456789ABCDEFabcdef/fedcba9876543210543210/
```

Or 36 bytes if you only need to support one case.

Comment: You don't need to support both lowercase and uppercase.

Comment: @MartinBüttner the question seems to require support for both cases in the input, but not in the output.  Like my bash+tr solution, this solution supports both on input but only writes lower-case output.

Comment: You've got an extra `0` in your code, between the `9` and `A` (byte count is correct though, must be a copying error).

Comment: The question says you can choose which case your input and output are.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 85 bytes

My first submission, it will probably be the longest (85 bytes) but hey, you got to start somewhere.
In Haskell:

```
import Numeric;f=('#':).concatMap((flip showHex)"".(15-).fst.head.readHex.(:[])).tail
```

It's using the same subtract from 15 trick I saw other people use.

I also tried using printf along with the other trick (subtract 8^8 - 1) and it works in ghci but for some reason it doesn't compile:

```
g=printf "#%06x" .(8^8-1-).fst.head.readHex.tail
```

If someone could make this work that would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. These are very good answers (better than I could do in Haskell!). However, there is a common answer format for code-golf challenges which lets the Leaderboard snippet put your answer in the leaderboard. I'll edit it in for you; you can accept or deny the edit.

Comment: To reply to other users' comments, type `@username`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Any time! Do you want to have a go at some of my challenges? [Analyse your chair](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67522/analyse-your-chair) and [Map string to Hilbert Curve](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66958/map-string-to-hilbert-curve) are my favourites, although the Hilbert curve one is really hard.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Certainly, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 94 bytes

```
t(char*b){for(int i;i=*b;++b)*b=i>96&i<103?150-i:i>64&i<71|i>47&i<54?118-i:i>53&i<58?111-i:i;}
```

Function takes in a char array, returns inverse value. Produces uppercase letters for response. The code flips each ASCII hex character to its inverse if it's valid, ignores it otherwise.

Comment: You can save some space by globally declaring `i` before the function: `i;`

Answer (score 1):

## 2, 18 chars / 34 bytes

```
ïē/\w⌿,↪(ḏ-`ᶍ⦃$}”ⓧ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=%23ffffff&code=%C3%AF%C4%93%2F%5Cw%E2%8C%BF%2C%E2%86%AA%28%E1%B8%8F-%60%E1%B6%8D%E2%A6%83%24%7D%E2%80%9D%E2%93%A7)</kbd>

Using a version created after the challenge.

## Explanation

```
ïē/\w⌿,↪(ḏ-`ᶍ⦃$}”ⓧ // implicit: ï=input, ḏ=15
ïē/\w⌿,             // replace all alphanumeric chars in ï with:
       ↪(ḏ-`ᶍ⦃$}”ⓧ // (15 - char's decimal form) converted to hex
                    // implicit output
```

## Non-competitive solution, 15 chars / 29 bytes

```
ïē/\w⌿,↪(ḏ-`ᶍ⦃$}”ⓧ
```

Uses transliteration.

Comment: Can you add a competitive version as well, so we can see how the language stacks up?

Comment: Sure. See new edit.

Comment: Nice use of the APL symbol `⌿`.

Comment: Hehe, that symbol was the one that made the most sense for `/g`.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 96

```
x=input()
print("#")
for i in range(3):
    print(hex(255-int(x[(1+2*i)]+x[(2+2*i)],16))[2:4])
```

First code golf, please give opinions :)

Comment: You are allowed to require the input be in `"quotes"` btw, so `input()` works. You don't need the newline and indent on the for loop, and `range` works just fine. There are also a couple spaces you can remove.

Comment: `int("ff", 16)` can be replaced with just `255`.

Comment: Do you need the parentheses inside the brackets after each x?

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>53</s> 49 bytes

```c
p(*s){printf("#%06x",0xffffff-wcstol(s+1,0,16));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///v0BDq1izuqAoM68kTUNJWdXArEJJx6AiDQx0y5OLS/JzNIq1DXUMdAzNNDWta//nJmbmaWhWcykoFGj4KClDVCppWheUlhRrKAEZMJnEpOSUVKwySYkpyYlJ2GQMjY3NTYywmmaYZJRsjE3GPM08zcIARab2PwA)

-4 thanks to @jdt

Comment: suggest using wide chars for -4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge)-[98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 37 bytes

```
~,v>v
~f<^ s
>,^ >-:9w>'0+
^+W'    ]^
```

This takes input in lowercase, outputs the answer in lowercase, then enters an infinite loop.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/v06nzK6Mqy7NJk6hmMtOJ07BTtfKstxO3UCbK047XF0BCGLj/v9XTjRMMko2BgA)

[40 byte version that terminates](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/v06nzK6MSyHNJk6huM5BmctOJ07BTtfKstxO3UCbK047XF0BCGLj/v9XTjRMMko2BgA)

### Explanation

```
~,v
```

This gets the first character of the input (which is always `#`), outputs it unchanged, and enters the loop.

```
~f<  s
```

At the start of the loop, `f` pushes `15` onto the stack, `~` gets the next character of the input, and `s` puts that character one space to its left in the source code (without executing it).

```
   >v
   ^I
```

(I'm using `I` to represent the character from the input that is now in the source code.) This section loops back around to execute that character. Every character in the range `0-9` or `a-f` pushes the corresponding hex value on the stack.

```
 
 
    >-:9w
```

The hex value is subtracted from `15` (the previous top of the stack) to get its complement. `:9w` creates a copy of the complement, and compares the copy with `9`, with the IP going down, up or right depending on whether it is greater, less than, or equal.

```
 
 
         >
        ]^
```

If the complement is greater than 9, the IP goes down and hits the `]` ("turn right") from above, turning to move left. If the copy was less than 9, the IP goes up and hits the `]` from below, turning to move right. In that case, it gets redirected back to the third line. If the copy was exactly 9, the IP goes right and hits the `>` immediately.

```
 
 
          '0+
```

If the complement is less than or equal to 9 (i.e. a digit), it is added to ASCII 48 (`0`) to produce the correct digit.

```
 
 
 
^+W'
```

If the complement is greater than 9, it is added to ASCII 87 (`W`) to produce the correct character (in the range `a-f`).

```
  <
>,^
```

In all cases, the character corresponding to the complement is printed and the IP moves back to the start of the loop.

The loop repeats, outputting the complement of every hex digit in the input.

After we print the answer, the input has been completely used up. Once EOF is reached, `~` reflects the IP. This means that `~f<` is now an infinite loop that pushes `15` on the stack forever. This doesn't produce any effects (except for possibly crashing), so we don't care about it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 46 bytes

```julia
h->'#'repr(~parse(UInt,h[2:7];base=16))[13:18]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcy9bsMgFIbh3VdxFIaAlEYG7BglIqOlXkCnKAN/VkAWtbArZYh66y6mnfuND@clfI1e0efay/Xxdt2jfXJTwt@TSrPDH@9xOTxu7NzdL1rNTtITITfKz1Tc1@EzAfYHCAR8hHka/XLEySk7@uhmTEgFeT32RMoArxdMyccF756wI1DeCowRe5DXcvjnPc5/Sgn@3yr8VmGrXLQrGsoAUF1WIaWNdRu0DWc0g1bWKJ2haRlvmwpRzruGZXDGCG1zQjUzfEtcY7mpUDd0g6gziFrU3fAD)

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 40 bytes

```julia
h->"#"hex(~parse(UInt,h[2:7],16))[11:16]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fczNboQgFIbhvVdxIhtInEZAxUzCLE16AV1NZoH8RIihRm0yi0lv3SLtut/y4byEr9mr7hjkMV1uJSon@8Tfi1o3iz/e415Nd3YVj4p2hNwpvdLucbjPFbCvIBDwEbZl9vsbXq0ys492w4QUkDZgT6QM8HrBsvq44/IJJYH8lmGO2IO85cM/H3D6U0rw/1bhtwpnZaM5kMsDQHVegdSojT2hbTijCUZltBoTNC3jbVMgyrloWAKrdT@alNCRaX4mtjFcF0g44fo6QV/3tXA/)

Simply a bitwise not (`~`) on the full number, in hex, the rest around is to parse and print the numbers in hexadecimal and keeping the last 6 numbers

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8 bytes (16 nibbles)

```
`($+.$hex- 15hex
```

```
`($+.$hex- 15hex
`($                 # output the first element of input (the '#') 
                    # and save the rest;
    .$              # now, map over the rest
             hex    #   convert from hex,
         - 15       #   subtract from 15,
      hex           #   and convert back to hex
   +                # and convert the resulting list of characters to a string
                    # (which is implicitly output after the '#')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 111 bytes

```go
import(."strconv";."fmt")
func f(s string)string{n,_:=ParseInt(s[1:],16,64)
return Sprintf("#%06x",0xffffff-n)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LZBLasMwEIbX1SkGmYAFSvArtklJl4XuAl22JZFlyZg04yApJRBykm5CocfoprfobSo_ZjPwzfwz88_nV9Pdfo5C7kWj4CBaJO3h2Bm3oNaZFhtLv09Oz8u_buThUJAdftD7BdUHRxnRJ5SgQwujhI3pgny7Wm-EseoJXWhf4tUbj3OeZ4wY5U4G4fnoG50OaTCL8jPl0VkPMUd2ndb-DsP7w0IGFyKFVRZWa3hs1Xttw10wKgCCaAgSiErWqgfLLE1iDypRS1F5kC2TdJmRIE7TIks8UFKWVe0lcZXItJeorE4lCQpd6DLyoIzKqNA777EzsOXYrzYC_a_GSy7kbjN5mFmYP8DMviLlgNw_BBkjVzI5ud3G_A8)

Answer (score 0):

## TeaScript, 24 bytes

```
"#"+S(8**8-1-xS1)t16))x6
```

Bugs in the interpreter aren't letting me get this shorter :(

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22%5C%22%23%5C%22%2BS(8**8-1-xS1)t16))x6%22&inputs=%5B%22%23FFFFFF%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false%7D)

Comment: Downvote explanation? It works for all the test cases

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 16 bytes

```
qA,'G,65>+s_W%er
```

This is fairly long because CJam handles base changes differently, so it was shorter to just do transliteration. See my [Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68308/29750) for more on transliteration.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qA%2C'G%2C65%3E%2Bs_W%25er&input=%23A1B2C3)

#### Explanation

```
q      e# Get the input
A,     e# Push [0 1 ... 8 9]
'G,65> e# Push "ABCDEF"
+s     e# Combine and convert to string
_W%    e# Make a copy and reverse it
er     e# Replace each character in the first string with
       e# the corresponding character in the second
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 44 bytes

Originally I used `256^3`, then `16^6`. Then I saw Pietu1998's `8^8` and now this solution uses that instead.

```
"#{:06x}".format(8**8-1-int(input()[1:],16))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bash + tr, 35 bytes

```
tr 0-9A-Fa-f fedcba9876543210543210
```

Output is always lowercase.

Unfortunately "tr" does not take ranges in reverse order so I had to spell them out.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 147 bytes

```
void p(char s[]){char c[3];int i=1;printf("#");while(i<6){strncpy(c,s+i++,2);i++;int x=255-strtol(c,NULL,16);x<10?printf("0%x",x):printf("%x",x);}}
```

Used strtol to convert from hex string to int then subtracted the number from 255 to get the compliment like the original post said. I am, however, wondering if there is a way to pass a range of characters from s to strtol so I don't have to waste a bunch of bytes copying to a new string?

Comment: I don't think compilers usually enforce function returns and default to int, so you an probably omit the `void` return type?

Answer (score 0):

### R, 62 bytes

```
f=function(a)sprintf('#%06x',(8^8-1)-strtoi(substr(a,2,7),16))
```

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, 48 bytes

```
param($a)"#{0:x6}"-f(16MB-1-("0x"+$a.Trim('#')))
```

Necessarily takes input via `param($a)` as a string, delimited with `'` or `"`, since `C:\Tools\Scripts\Golfing> .\complementary-colors #a1b2c3` on the PowerShell command line will treat `#a1b2c3` as a comment and summarily ignore it.

Left-to-right, the `"#{0:x6}"-f(...)` formats our output calculations back into hexadecimal with a guaranteed 6 characters (to account for input `#ffffff`). Inside the parens, we subtract our input number from `0xffffff`. We do this by leveraging the fact that PowerShell parses hexadecimal numbers in format `0xNNN`, so we construct a proper-format hex number from our input number `$a`. (Note that concatenation plus `.Trim()` is shorter than `.Replace()` here by one byte.) We also leverage the `MB` unary operator via `16MB-1` to construct `16777215` instead of `0xffffff`.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 37 bytes

```php
printf('#%06x',8**8-1-hexdec($argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYhLCsIwFAD3OYXwlNpiIb@aQAVXigvB3kCSl8R204baRU9vDJ3FDEzsY7pcY3ach3EJxwIO9LwWJ11VumZ171fn8bg382csyzZ57Kdd9@jet9ezTRA2CBiLzuda49BYAkwIJXn@zHIUBFRQQVMCdINAIwVnubLhopEEPKK2Ln8vnUACmmqqwm@KyzCN31Tf/w)

Or if you prefer to be more bit-wise (and byte-foolish) about it:

#### [PHP](https://php.net/), 38 bytes

```php
printf('#%06x',~hexdec($argn)&8**8-1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYi9CsIwGAD3PIXwqf3BQtKkJlDBSXEQ7BtI8iWxXdpQO3Ty0Y3BG@7gQh/i6RySwzyMi88z2NHjmh0@vVutw3yr59dY7FVZqooVbXTYT5vu1j0vj3sbwf8hoA1al2q0RW0IMM6lqNNnpkZOQHrpFSVA/xBoBK9Zqmhq3ggCDlEZm74TliMBRRWV/juFZZjGd6yuPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kfḲṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPVImY29kZT1rZiVFMSVCOCVCMiVFMSVCOSU4NiZmb290ZXI9TCZpbnB1dD0lMjIlMjNmZmZmZmYlMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwJTIyJTIzMDAwMDAwJTIyJTBBJTIyJTIzYWJjZGVmJTIyJTIwLSUzRSUyMCUyMiUyMzU0MzIxMCUyMiUwQSUyMiUyM2JhZGNhYiUyMiUyMC0lM0UlMjAlMjIlMjM0NTIzNTQlMjIlMEElMjIlMjMxMzM3NDIlMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwJTIyJTIzZWNjOGJkJTIyJTBBJTIyJTIzYTFiMmMzJTIyJTIwLSUzRSUyMCUyMiUyMzVlNGQzYyUyMiUwQSUyMiUyMzdmN2Y4MCUyMiUyMC0lM0UlMjAlMjIlMjM4MDgwN2YlMjImZmxhZ3M9Qw==)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḣ²Hɠ⁻_Ḥ2ṛ'#
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCVBMyVDMiVCMkglQzklQTAlRTIlODElQkJfJUUxJUI4JUE0MiVFMSVCOSU5QiclMjMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lMjIlMjNmZmZmZmYlMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwJTIyJTIzMDAwMDAwJTIyJTBBJTIyJTIzYWJjZGVmJTIyJTIwLSUzRSUyMCUyMiUyMzU0MzIxMCUyMiUwQSUyMiUyM2JhZGNhYiUyMiUyMC0lM0UlMjAlMjIlMjM0NTIzNTQlMjIlMEElMjIlMjMxMzM3NDIlMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwJTIyJTIzZWNjOGJkJTIyJTBBJTIyJTIzYTFiMmMzJTIyJTIwLSUzRSUyMCUyMiUyMzVlNGQzYyUyMiUwQSUyMiUyMzdmN2Y4MCUyMiUyMC0lM0UlMjAlMjIlMjM4MDgwN2YlMjImZmxhZ3M9Q2o=)

##### Explanation

```python
kfḲṆ  # Implicit input
kf    # Hexadecimal characters: "0123456789ABCDEF"
  Ḳ   # Bifurcate: duplicate and reverse
   Ṇ  # Transliterate: [0-9A-F] -> [F-A9-0]
      # Implicit output
```

```python
ḣ²Hɠ⁻_Ḥ2ṛ'#  '# Implicit input
ḣ             # Remove the leading "#"
 ²            # Split into pairs
  H           # Convert each from hexadecimal
   ɠ⁻_        # Subtract each from 255
      Ḥ       # Convert each to hexadecimal
       2ṛ     # Pad with 0s to length 2
         '#  '# Push "#" to the stack
              # Implicit output of joined stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->s{"#%6x"%(8**8-1-s[1..].hex)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhb7de2Kq5WUVc0qlFQ1LLS0LHQNdYujDfX0YvUyUis0ayGqNhaUlhQruEUrKScmJaekpinFQsQXLIDQAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
15ÝhÂ‡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0PTw3IzDTY8aFv7/r@zo5Ozi6gYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/Q9PDczMONz1qWPhf53@0krIbGCjpKCkbgAGI5ejk7OIKFjM1MTYyBIs5Obo4OzqBWCamRsamJiCWobGxuYkRiOXq7Gzh5ALWa@hk5GwM1utq4mLsDGKZu5m7WYBNsTCwMDB3U4oFAA).

**Or with the more straight-forward approach (15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)):**

```
ćs2ôH₅αh2jð0:J«
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SHux0eEtHo@aWs9tzDDKOrzBwMrr0Or//5UdnZxdXN0A) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/I@3FRoe3eDxqaj23McMo6/AGAyuvQ6v/6/yPVlJ2AwMlHSVlAzAAsRydnF1cwWKmJsZGhmAxJ0cXZ0cnEMvE1MjY1ATEMjQ2NjcxArFcnZ0tnFzAeg2djJyNwXpdTVyMnUEsczdzNwuwKRYGFgbmYJPdDEFQKRYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
15Ý         # Push a list in the range [0,15]
   h        # Convert each integer to a hexadecimal character
    Â       # Bifurcate this list; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
     ‡      # Transliterate the (implicit) input-string using these two lists
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

```python
ć           # Extract head of the (implicit) input-string; push remainder-string and
            # first item separately to the stack
s           # Swap so the remainder-string is at the top
 2ô         # Split it into pairs
        H   # Convert each string in the triplet from hexadecimal to an integer
         ₅α # Take the absolute difference with 255
        h   # Convert it back to hexadecimal
   2jð0:    # Pad leading 0s to single hexadecimal characters if necessary:
   2j       #  Pad potential leading spaces to make all strings of length 2
     ð0:    #  Then replace all spaces with 0s
 J          # Join the triplet of pairs back to a string
«           # Append it back to the "#" that's on the stack
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```